# Change two different backgrounds by clicking a button

Tags: android, button, background

With android studio I'm working on a button and i want that every time i click it THE BACKGROUND OF THE BUTTON change and when i do not , there is another background. I don't have a clue of how to do that, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an xml file in `/res/drawable` folder of your project. If a folder named `drawable` is not present in the /res directory, create it. As an example, name the xml file `button_bg.xml`

Copy and paste the following code in `button_bg.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_when_pressed" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_drawable" />
</selector>
```

`drawable_when_pressed` and `default_drawable` are drawable resources that you want to use as the button's background. When the button is pressed, button's background will be `drawable_when_pressed`. Otherwise, it will be `default_drawable`.

You will set this drawable (button_bg.xml) to the button's background. Here's how to use this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="Button" />
```

This is a very basic form of a state list drawable. You can read up more on this here: [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Answer (score 2):

Xml Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change"
    android:onClick="changeBack" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add this code to your Activity

```
public boolean firstImage = true;
public void changeBack(View view)
{
    if (firstImage)
        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.secondimage);
    else
        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.firstimage);
    firstImage = !firstImage;
}
```